# An arduino servo radar system

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to make something like roomba. Everything is going perfect. I want to have an ultrasonic sensor mounted on servo motor which rotate it from 0 deg to 180 deg & from 180 deg to 0 deg and the ultrasonic sensor will detect if there is any obstacles ahead. I want to take distance from the sensor. The servo motor rotates perfectly alone but when i tries to calculates the distance by the sensor which is mounted on it. The servo stops rotating. I have seen such type of systems in many projects like obstacles avoiding cars etc but i am unable to solve this problem. Can anybody tell me what i can do to solve this problem.

The code I am trying:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define trigPin 2
#define echoPin 3
long duration;
int distanceCm;
Servo myservo; 

int pos = 0;  

void setup() {
myservo.attach(9); 
myservo.write(0);
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) 
  {
    myservo.write(pos); 
    //delay(500);
   int distance = calculate_distance();
    Serial.println(distance);       
  }
  delay(100);
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) 
  {
    myservo.write(pos);  
    //delay(500);  
   int distance = calculate_distance();
    Serial.println(distance); 
  }
  delay(100);
}

int calculate_distance()
{

digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
distanceCm = duration*0.034/2;

return distanceCm;

}
```

Comment: Can it be, that it doesn't stop moving, but only moving 1 degree per second? If for whatever reason `pulseIn()` does not sense a HIGH pulse, it will wait for it, until the timeout has passed, which defaults to 1s. That would make the movement very very slow

Comment: change the step size to 15 degrees

Comment: Yeah, add a timeout to the `pulseIn()` call